# decoding an array from json into PHP and unable to access elements of array using keys

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON similar to the following:

```
{"internalArray": {"201": "A", "202": "B", "5": "C", "46": "D"}, 
 "data": "ABCDEFG", 
 "data2": "TSXPIIF"}
```

I use the following PHP code to decode it:

```
$jsonOutput = json_decode($output);
```

I would like to get access to the "internalArray" from the JSON data, so I reference it using the following:

```
$internalArray = $jsonOutput->{'internalArray'};
```

When I do a var_dump on $internalArray

```
object(stdClass)#4 (4) 
{ ["201"]=> string(1) "A" 
     ["202"]=> string(1) "B" 
     ["5"]=> string(1) "C" 
     ["46"]=> string(1) "D" 
}
```

I figured out that I could cast this to an array, so I did the following:

```
$internalArray = (array) $jsonOutput->{'internalArray'};
```

However, now that I have this array, I can't appear to access it using values like

```
$internalArray["202"], $internalArray["201"], etc.
```

When I try to access it via the keys, it returns NULL.  However, when I have code like this:

```
foreach ($internalArray as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key . "," . $value;
}
```

it prints out the values as expected, like "202,A", etc.

However, in the same code if I change it to

```
foreach ($internalArray as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key . "," . $internalArray[$key];
}
```

it doesn't work!

Can anyone explain why I can't access the values in $internalArray using the keys?  Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want an associative array, you can ask PHP for an associative array (see documentation for [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)):

```
$jsonOutput = json_decode($output, true);

var_dump($jsonOutput['internalArray']);
```

Produces:

```
array(4) {
  [201]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [202]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [46]=>
  string(1) "D"
}
```

---

Back to your issue, your code would still work *if* the keys in the internal array were not numeric. What is happening here is a little peculiar: PHP doesn't allow you to have numeric strings (eg: `'201'`, `'46'`) as keys for an array.

Numeric strings keys will be converted to numbers keys instead. So when you do `$arr['201']` PHP will look for `$arr[201]` instead. However, when you cast your object into an array, it looks like the array keys remain strings (eg: `$arr['201']`). Now the actual array has a numeric string key, but whenever you try to access it, PHP looks for an int key and never finds it, giving you `NULL`.

In fact, [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) notes that:

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a **few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible**; (...)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.  In terms of accessing the array, I was able to use strval to get a proper access into the array.

Comment: @steve8918 Out of curiosity, how did you solve the array access problem?

Comment: I used strval() to turn the integer into a string, and then accessed the values like $internalArray[strval($i)].  That appears to work for me.

Comment: @steve8918 Hmmm, I don't think that makes a difference. See: http://codepad.org/9nc0eJHk (note how I get `NULL` regardless of how I try to access `$objArr['5']`); numeric strings as keys in arrays are rendered inaccessible. If you have a number as the key, it gets converted to an int no matter what.

Comment: weird.  I used your first suggestion, and added "true" to json_decode and that solved my problem.  Using that associative array I was able to use strval() to index my values.  But yes, without adding the true to json_decode, nothing worked for me, like your first example showed.

Comment: @steve8918 If you have an associative array, you don't need `strval`

Answer (score 1):

Because the data is not array it is an object. Hence you can't use it by this code snippet

```
foreach ($internalArray as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key . "," . $internalArray[$key];
}
```

and use for associate array `json_decode($output, true);`