# Converting objects to arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, typecasting-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diddling with arrays with numeric string keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846936/diddling-with-arrays-with-numeric-string-keys)

As specified in PHP's manual, we can do type casting on objects and covert them to array as follows:

```
$arrayResult = (array)$someObject;
```

But I found very interesting remark in documentation:

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: **integer properties are innaccessible**

What does **"integer properties"** stands for?

Comment: `$obj->{10} = 'this is int prop';` - for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846936/diddling-with-arrays-with-numeric-string-keys

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090328/undefined-offset-while-accessing-array-element-which-exists

Answer (score 0):

I believe this means that you cannot use typical integer properties of arrays to iterate through, such as in a for loop.  The elements are not integer-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the example:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->{'1'} = 1;
$arr = (array) $obj;
var_dump($arr);
var_dump(isset($arr[1]));  // will get false
```